# API authentication only giving code 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'am programming a website with the use of any api. I'm writting javascript in Jquery and making request with ajax. I have a problem with authentication when someone makes a request to the api. They get a token from when they log in, that they should use for authentication.

```
var token;
var games;

function login() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth',
  data: JSON.stringify({'emailAddress':email,'password':password}),
  success: function(jtoken) {
   token = JSON.stringify(jtoken);
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json'
});
getGames();
}
```

Here i get back the token when a user logs in that I later use to authenticate other requests.

```
function getGames(){
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/me/game',
  data: {api_token: token},
  success: function(result){
    games = JSON.parse(result);
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType:'text'
});
```

This is were i request games from a json file but i only get the error code 402.
EDIT: I'am noticing now the first ajax request is running two times. the first giving me the code 204 and then 200 on the second. And it is giving me an undefined token. Why is it acting like that?

Comment: `token` will be `undefined` outside of it's scope

Comment: Can you please explain why and how do i fix it?

Comment: Shouldnt the token be passed in as an HTTP header, rather than in the body?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a timing problem:

Above getGames is being called before the ajax login has a chance to complete.  Instead, call getGames in the success function so you know the auth is done.

```
var token;
var games;

function login() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth',
  data: JSON.stringify({'emailAddress':email,'password':password}),
  success: function(jtoken) {
   token = JSON.stringify(jtoken);
   getGames();
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json'
});

}
```